# Why my function in Javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying differents methods to implement a function, but one o them isn't working.
Are this syntax correct?:

```
function funcao2()
        {
            alert('Tudo bem?');
        }funcao2();
```

I have a **'self invoking function'**, an **'anonymous function'** and a **'function attributed to a variable'**, but the second aren't working. See the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Função de auto-invocação anônima ou função recursiva anônima
    (function(){
        alert('Oi');
    })();
    //Função anônima
    document.onload = function(){
        alert('Página carregada');
    };
    //Atribuir função a uma variável e executá-la em seguida
    var funcao = function(){
        alert('Oi novamente');
    }; funcao();
```

Comment: `document.onload` should be `window.onload`, `document` has the `onreadystatechange` event, the `window` loads

Comment: ok, thanks :). Are this syntax right, or I need to use ";" after closing the block?:
function funcao2()
        {
            alert('Tudo bem?');
        }funcao2();

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem throw that up as an answer before someone poaches it! +1

Comment: The semi-color(`;`) is optional, but in the last case (`fucao`) it's preferable to separate the function definition and the actual call with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commented this, seems to be what the OP wanted to know, so posting it as an answer:

`document.onload` should be `window.onload`, `document` has the `onreadystatechange` event, the `window` loads

related:

when using the `document.onreadystatechange` event, check the status and readystate properties:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(e)
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        //only now, the document is loaded
        return;
    }
    //do stuff on readyState 1,2,3... <-- usefull when loading is likely to fail
}
```